# rewrite rule in .htacces

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I want to rewrite a link to display another url in the navbar but it keeps failing fo rome reason.

**old url:** http://subdomain.domain.be/external/pdfjs-2.1.266-dist/web/viewer.html

**new url:** http://subdomain.domain.be/example

I thought this would work but seems like there is something wrong.

```
RewriteRule ^external/pdfjs-2\.1\.266-dist/web/viewer\.html$ /example?&%{QUERY_STRING}
```

thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: What’s with the `?&%{QUERY_STRING}` at the end, when you say you want `/example` only? And what is the link you actually want to see on the client side? If you just want to use `/example` for your link, and have that rewrite to `/external/pdfjs-2.1.266-dist/web/viewer.html` _internally_, because that is where the file actually resides - well then you are trying to rewrite in the wrong direction to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

As @04FS mused in the comment to the question this reads like you are approaching this the wrong way 'round...

If `/example` is the like that is handed out, so actually requested by the clients, then you want to internally rewrite that. So that the incoming request gets mapped onto the existing internal resource:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?example$ /external/pdfjs-2.1.266-dist/web/viewer.html [END]
```

In case you receive an internal server error (http status 500) using the rule above then chances are that you operate a very old version of the apache http server. You will see a definite hint to an unsupported `[END]` flag in your http servers error log file in that case. You can either try to upgrade or use the older `[L]` flag, it probably will work the same in this situation, though that depends a bit on your setup.

This implementation will work likewise in the http servers host configuration or inside a dynamic configuration file (".htaccess" file). Obviously the rewriting module needs to be loaded inside the http server and enabled in the http host. In case you use a dynamic configuration file you need to take care that it's interpretation is enabled at all in the host configuration and that it is located in the host's `DOCUMENT_ROOT` folder.

And a general remark: you should always prefer to place such rules in the http servers host configuration instead of using dynamic configuration files (".htaccess"). Those dynamic configuration files add complexity, are often a cause of unexpected behavior, hard to debug and they really slow down the http server. They are only provided as a last option for situations where you do not have access to the real http servers host configuration (read: really cheap service providers) or for applications insisting on writing their own rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).